# Transforming multidimensional array to 2d

Tags: php, arrays

I've successfully built a multidimensional array that dumps this:

```
0 => array:11 [▼
  "category_code" => "123"
  "category_name" => "Testing"
  "category_description" => "This is a test category"
  19738 => array:5 [▼
    "identifier" => "720368842943"
    "description" => Test Description One
    "count" => 4
    "details" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "detail_code" => "2751"
        "detail_code2" => "43"
        "detail_specifier" => "Detail One"
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "detail_code" => "2681"
        "detail_code2" => "9"
        "detail_specifier" => "Detail Two"
      ]
    ]
    "prices" => array:1 [▼
      "01" => "1129.00"
    ]
  ]
  19739 => array:5 [▼
    "identifier" => "720368844121"
    "description" => "Test Description Two"
    "count" => 4
    "details" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "detail_code" => "2751"
        "detail_code2" => "43"
        "detail_specifier" => "Detail One"
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "detail_code" => "2681"
        "detail_code2" => "9"
        "detail_specifier" => "Detail Two"
      ]
    ]
    "prices" => array:1 [▼
      "01" => "1490.00"
    ]
  ]
```

But for my purposes I actually need a 2d array where one element would be the category fields, then each item and all of its info would be another element so that I can export this as rows.

How can I make this a 2d array?

```
$allCategoryResult= array();

foreach($prices->categories as $category){ 
    $categoryItem = array(); 
    $categoryItem["category_code"] = $category->category_code;
    $categoryItem["category_name"] = $category->category_name; 
    $categoryItem["category_desc"] = $category->category_desc;

    foreach($category->skus as $sku){
        $skuItem = array(); 

        $skuItem["identifier"] = $sku->sku_info->identifier;
        $skuItem["description"] = $sku->sku_info->item->description;
        $skuItem["count"] = $sku->sku_info->item->item_type->count;

        $skuItem["details"] = array(); 
        foreach ($sku->sku_info->details as $details) {
            $detailsItem = array(); 
            $detailsItem["detail_code"] = $details->detail_code;
            $detailsItem["detail_code2"] = $details->detail_code2;
            $detailsItem["detail_specifier"] = $details->detail_specifier;
            $skuItem["details"][] = $detailsItem; 
        }

        $skuItem["prices"] = get_object_vars($sku->prices);


        $itemCode = $sku->sku_info->item->item_code;
        $categoryItem[$itemCode] = $skuItem; 
    }
    $allCategoryResult[] = $categoryItem; 
}
```

Example of expected output

```
0 => array: [▼
  "category_code" => "123"
  "category_name" => "Testing"
  "category_description" => "This is a test category"
  Array:[ 
    "item-code" => 19738 
    "identifier" => "720368842943"
    "description" => Test Description One
    "count" => 4
    "detail_code" => "2751"
    "detail_code2" => "43"
    "detail_specifier" => "Detail One"
    "detail_code" => "2681"
    "detail_code2" => "9"
    "detail_specifier" => "Detail Two"
    "01" => "1129.00"
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Can you post expected output? It's not obvious to me how "details" should be organized, for example.

Comment: Yes one moment...

Comment: Updated now, something like that. Basically every attribute for products should be in one product array. So a category with 3 products would be 4 arrays that I could export as 4 rows

Comment: What you posted isn't possible in PHP. You have various duplicate keys in an array.

Comment: That's why I was hoping I could loop on details just to get each value, even if I don't have keys

Comment: I did the best I could with that on mobile to show the structure I want, but I just want the values of each item

Comment: @ggorlen I guess the name keys could be hypothetically replaced with index numbers in that  case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is don't nest the other details of `sku` in a separate array. Just push it to `skuitems` array Something like below

```
$allCategoryResult= array();

foreach($prices->categories as $category){ 
    $categoryItem = array(); 
    $categoryItem["category_code"] = $category->category_code;
    $categoryItem["category_name"] = $category->category_name; 
    $categoryItem["category_desc"] = $category->category_desc;

    foreach($category->skus as $sku){
        $skuItem = array(); 

        $skuItem["identifier"] = $sku->sku_info->identifier;
        $skuItem["description"] = $sku->sku_info->item->description;
        $skuItem["count"] = $sku->sku_info->item->item_type->count;

        $skuItem["details"] = array(); 
        foreach ($sku->sku_info->details as $details) {
            $detailsItem = array(); 
            $skuItem["detail_code"] = $details->detail_code;                
            $skuItem["detail_code2"] = $details->detail_code2;
            $skuItem["detail_specifier1"] = $details->detail_specifier1;
            $skuItem["detail_specifier2"] = $details->detail_specifier2;     
        }

        array_push($skuItem,$sku->prices);


        $itemCode = $sku->sku_info->item->item_code;
        $categoryItem[$itemCode] = $skuItem; 
    }
    $allCategoryResult[] = $categoryItem; 
}
```

P.S: Array key should be unique so, you can't have two keys called with same name "detail_specifier", so have modified it accordingly here but YMMV.

Comment: This makes sense, but sense my details values have the same index names could I do this without named keys?

Comment: nope then you wouldn't know what's the array is referring to I mean you would end up something like `[0]=>'Detail One',[1]=>'Detail Two'` which might not make sense at all

Comment: other option would be you could nest them together as array like : `"detail_specifier"=>['Detail One', 'Detail Two']`

Comment: But that wouldn't necessarily matter if I'm exporting this to excel as rows right? I don't need to associate anything at that point I just need a category array with all the following product arrays values to print as rows

Comment: if you don't want assosiative array and you want indexed array you could just do `array_push($skuItem,$details->detail_code);` instead of `$skuItem["detail_code"] = $details->detail_code;` and do the same for all elements

Comment: Ok sorry for confusion I think that's what I meant. I don't really need associative to export to excel